# Converting JSP to Thymleaf: Attribute Name cannot be Null or Empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I am currently converting a number of `.jsp` pages to `HTML` using `Thymeleaf`. I have converted a number of these successfully but when checking any pages with form tags, I receive the following error:

```
Attribute name cannot be null or empty during the initial page load.
```

I have been following the guide on: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

**View Code**

```
    <!-- Registration Form -->
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/register/processRegistrationForm}" th:object="${user}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- User name -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 
                        <input type="text" th:field:="*{userName}" placeholder="Username (*)" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> 
                        <input type="text" th:field:="*{password}" placeholder="First Name (*)" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
@GetMapping("/showRegistrationForm")
public String showMyRegistrationPage(
        Model theModel) {

    theModel.addAttribute("user", new UserRegistrationDto());

    return "Login/registration-form";
}

@PostMapping("/processRegistrationForm")
public String processRegistrationForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute ("user") UserRegistrationDto userDto, 
            BindingResult theBindingResult, 
            Model theModel) {

    String userName = userDto.getUserName();
    logger.info("Processing registration form for: " + userName);

    // form validation
     if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()){
         return "Login/registration-form";
        }

    // check the database if user already exists
    User existing = userService.findByUserName(userName);
    if (existing != null){
        theModel.addAttribute("user", new UserRegistrationDto());
        theModel.addAttribute("registrationError", "User name already exists.");

        logger.warning("User name already exists.");
        return "Login/registration-form";
    }
 // create user account                             
    userService.save(userDto);

    logger.info("Successfully created user: " + userName);

    return "redirect:/loginPage?rSuccess";      
}
```

**DTO Code**

```
public class UserRegistrationDto {

    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    private String password;
```

***Entity Code***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;

public User() {
}

public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email,
        Collection<Role> roles) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

The stack trace points to the issue being around the method:

```
@GetMapping("/showRegistrationForm")
public String showMyRegistrationPage(
```

& reads with

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/Login/registration-form.html]")
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute name cannot be null or empty
```

This only occurs when using the ***th:field:="*{}"*** & works fine when leaving the page as `.jsp`.

I cannot see an issue with the code. 
Would anyone have an idea into what is causing this?

I have tried removing validation from the `DTO` in the off chance it was being caused by that, but the error message did not change.

Comment: Can you try `th:field=` (remove `colon` i.e `:` before `=`)? One more suggestion, put `existing` variable instead of `new UserRegistrationDto()` into the line `theModel.addAttribute("user", new UserRegistrationDto());`

Comment: Hi Johir! it was the second : can't believe I missed that! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about these two lines:

```
<input type="text" th:field:="*{userName}" placeholder="Username (*)" class="form-control" />

<input type="text" th:field:="*{password}" placeholder="First Name (*)" class="form-control" />
```

Since you put a column "`:`" after `th:field`it might give you an error.  So those two lines should be like these:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" placeholder="Username (*)" class="form-control" />

<input type="text" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="First Name (*)" class="form-control" />
```

Since thymeleaf doesn't provide a good explanation of the problem or the problematic line number, it becomes really a headache to find the problem. It's just saying "Attribute Name cannot be Null or Empty" and you're just searching empty attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, I just decreasing the error 1 by 1. So I was commented on each input and every form. And the problem just at here

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register/processRegistrationForm}" th:object="${user}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

At `th:object="${user}"`, maybe this trick can help you a bit since this question not solve yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late but i think i see what the problem is.

```
th:field:="*{password}"
```

There is a `:` too much

should be

```
th:field="*{password}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).